# Is CMCG (Constrained Maximum-Weight Connected Graph) problem NP-complete?

Tags: graphs, np-complete, weighted-graphs, subgraphs

MCG Problem: Consider a positive integer R and an undirected graph G = (V, E), in which each vertex is assigned a weight (or value). The maximum-weight connected graph (MCG) problem
is to find a subgraph with R vertices that is connected and maximizes the sum of the weights
(or values) of the R vertices.

CMCG Problem: The CMCG problem is the MCG problem with a constraint of having one predetermined (fixed) vertex included in the solution.

In [1](https://onlinelibrary-wiley-com.ezproxy.lib.ucalgary.ca/doi/epdf/10.1002/%28SICI%291520-6750%28199610%2943%3A7%3C985%3A%3AAID-NAV4%3E3.0.CO%3B2-9) it has been stated (First paragraph, Section 1) that MCG is an NP-complete problem, which is proved in [3] (However I could not find the technical report [3] anywhere on the internet).

In [2](https://link-springer-com.ezproxy.lib.ucalgary.ca/content/pdf/10.1023/A:1019188715963.pdf) it has been "claimed" that CMCG is NP-complete (second to last paragraph, Section 3). But did not provide any proof.

I want to know (and see a proof, if possible) that if CMCG is NP-complete.

In [1](https://onlinelibrary-wiley-com.ezproxy.lib.ucalgary.ca/doi/epdf/10.1002/%28SICI%291520-6750%28199610%2943%3A7%3C985%3A%3AAID-NAV4%3E3.0.CO%3B2-9) it has been shown that Steiner tree problem, which is NP-complete is a special case of the CMCG problem. Does it imply that CMCG is NP-complete?

[3]:Lee, H. F., and D. R. Dooly. The maximum-weight connected graph problem. Technical Report 93-4, Industrial Engineering, Southern Illinois University, 1993.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, note that you can reduce $CMCG$ to $MCG$ by setting the value of the node that must be in the set to the  sum of all positive weights of all other nodes $+1$ and then applying $MCG$ and retrieving the result set. Thus $CMCG\in NP$.

As proved in the paper the $NP$-complete Steiner-Tree problem can be reduced to $CMCG$ meaning that $CMCG$ is $NP$-hard. If a problem is in $NP$ and $NP$-hard it is by definition $NP$-complete.

Hope this helps.